# How can I pin a version of a Haskell dependency to a version of an underlying native dependency with Cabal?

Tags: haskell, dependency-management, cabal, cabal-install

In my particuar case, I have a dependency in my Cabal file on the Haskell package `bindings-libzip`. In particular, I could accept several different versions of `libzip`, e.g. `bindings-libzip-0.11` or `bindings-libzip-0.10`. These in turn have a dependency on the respective native C `libzip` libraries versions `0.11` and `0.10`.

Therefore I have `bindings-libzip >= 0.10 < 0.12` in my `.cabal` file.

The Haskell package `bindings-libzip-x` specifies with `PkgConfig-Depends` that `libzip` version `x` must be present on a client machine. Let's say a downstream user has version `0.10` of `libzip` installed. However, when pulling down my package, this user pulls down the latest dependencies possible and transitively pulls down version `0.11` of `bindings-libzip`. This causes the build process to error out with a message about an incorrect version of `libzip` installed.

Is there any way I can specify in my .cabal file to use `bindings-libzip-0.11` if and only if `pkg-config` detects version `0.11` of `libzip` and to use `bindings-libzip-0.10` if and only if `pkg-config` detects version `0.10` of `libzip`?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I'm submitting another answer because this uses another idea...

Using a custom Setup.hs with `defaultMainWithHooksArgs` allows you to inspect and modify the args to the `cabal configure` command.

This is a Setup.hs which does no modification:

```
import Distribution.Simple
import Distribution.Simple.Configure
import System.Environment

main = do
  args <- getArgs
  defaultMainWithHooksArgs simpleUserHooks args
```

If your .cabal file has a flag defined, e.g.:

```
Flag Foo
  Default:  False
```

then in the args you will see `"--flags=-foo"`. So the idea is:

1. Define two flags in the .cabal file - `use10` and `use11` to select which version of `bindings-libzip` to use.
2. In your custom Setup.hs determine which version to use.
3. Find the `"--flags=..."` arg and modify it appropriately before passing it along to `defaultMainWithHooksArgs`.

Answer (score 1):

I think the way to do this is with a custom `Setup.hs` file (specify `build-type: Custom` in the .cabal file.)

You can override specific stages of the build process by using a `main` like this:

```
main = defaultMainWithHooks $ simpleUserHooks { preConf = myPreConf }

myPreConf :: Args -> ConfigFlags -> IO HookedBuildInfo
myPreConf args configFlags = ...
```

It is also likely that overriding the `confHook` is what you want.

Some links:

- all cabal hooks: [`data UserHooks`](http://hackage.haskell.org/package/Cabal-1.22.4.0/docs/Distribution-Simple.html#t:UserHooks)
- standard sets of hooks: [(link)](http://hackage.haskell.org/package/Cabal-1.22.4.0/docs/Distribution-Simple.html#v:simpleUserHooks)

Examples of custom Setup.hs files overriding `confHook`:

[abcBridge](https://hackage.haskell.org/package/abcBridge-0.12/src/Setup.hs)
[arb-fft](https://hackage.haskell.org/package/arb-fft-0.2.0.2/src/Setup.hs)
[cabalmdvrpm](https://hackage.haskell.org/package/cabalmdvrpm-0.0.1/src/Setup.hs)
[darkplaces-text](https://hackage.haskell.org/package/darkplaces-text-0.2.1/src/Setup.hs)
[GLFW](https://hackage.haskell.org/package/GLFW-0.5.2.2/src/Setup.hs)
[happybara-webkit-server](https://hackage.haskell.org/package/happybara-webkit-server-0.0.1/src/Setup.hs)
[haskeline](https://hackage.haskell.org/package/haskeline-0.7.2.1/src/Setup.hs)
[HDBC-postgresql](https://hackage.haskell.org/package/HDBC-postgresql-2.3.2.3/src/Setup.hs)
[helics](https://hackage.haskell.org/package/helics-0.5.1/src/Setup.hs)
[hlbfgsb](https://hackage.haskell.org/package/hlbfgsb-0.0.1.0/src/Setup.hs)
[hlibsass](https://hackage.haskell.org/package/hlibsass-0.1.3.0/src/Setup.hs)
[hpqtypes](https://hackage.haskell.org/package/hpqtypes-1.4.2/src/Setup.hs)
[hruby](https://hackage.haskell.org/package/hruby-0.3.1.4/src/Setup.hs)
[hsqml](https://hackage.haskell.org/package/hsqml-0.3.3.0/src/Setup.hs)
[hubris](https://hackage.haskell.org/package/hubris-0.0.3/src/Setup.hs)
[illuminate](https://hackage.haskell.org/package/illuminate-0.1/src/Setup.hs)
[intel-aes](https://hackage.haskell.org/package/intel-aes-0.2.1.1/src/Setup.hs)
[keera-posture](https://hackage.haskell.org/package/keera-posture-0.1.4.4/src/Setup.hs)
[KiCS-debugger](https://hackage.haskell.org/package/KiCS-debugger-0.1.1/src/Setup.hs)
[libpq](https://hackage.haskell.org/package/libpq-0.4.1/src/Setup.hs)
[llvm-general](https://hackage.haskell.org/package/llvm-general-3.4.5.3/src/Setup.hs)
[morfeusz](https://hackage.haskell.org/package/morfeusz-0.4.2/src/Setup.hs)
[postgresql-libpq](https://hackage.haskell.org/package/postgresql-libpq-0.9.0.2/src/Setup.hs)
[tamarin-prover](https://hackage.haskell.org/package/tamarin-prover-0.8.6.1/src/Setup.hs)
[tamarin-prover-term](https://hackage.haskell.org/package/tamarin-prover-term-0.8.5.1/src/Setup.hs)
[tamarin-prover-theory](https://hackage.haskell.org/package/tamarin-prover-theory-0.8.6.0/src/Setup.hs)
[tamarin-prover-utils](https://hackage.haskell.org/package/tamarin-prover-utils-0.8.5.1/src/Setup.hs)
[voyeur](https://hackage.haskell.org/package/voyeur-0.1.0.1/src/Setup.hs)
[wxc](https://hackage.haskell.org/package/wxc-0.91.0.0/src/Setup.hs)
[wxcore](https://hackage.haskell.org/package/wxcore-0.91.0.0/src/Setup.hs)

In particular, the [hruby Setup.hs](https://hackage.haskell.org/package/hruby-0.3.1.4/src/Setup.hs) looks like it is doing something like what you want to do.