# Haskell inline-c multi-step build/link with Cabal

Tags: haskell, cabal, ffi, template-haskell

I am writing an FFI-heavy library that uses `inline-c`, and the build process is:

- run GHC on the `inline-c` files, produce C
- compile C produced in previous step into dynamic libraries
- compile Haskell interface while linking both the object files produced in step 2 and the dynlibs of the wrapped library.

QUESTION: Currently I'm doing the above in a makefile (see https://github.com/ocramz/petsc-hs/blob/master/makefile ), but I'd like to package it up in a Cabal file (working version : https://github.com/ocramz/petsc-hs/blob/master/petsc-hs.cabal).

SUB-QUESTIONS:

- How does one control the build/link sequence in Cabal?
- Are relative paths supported in Cabal? couldn't find this mentioned in the guide and bash-like `~` doesn't work

Thank you in advance for all pointers

Comment: I've looked at your cabal file and it seems you are following the recipe for using `inline-c`.  What exactly doesn't work?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> How does one control the build/link sequence in Cabal?

You can use `Build-Type: Custom` in your cabal file and control everything with a custom `Setup.hs`.

Have a look at the [`UserHooks` data type](http://hackage.haskell.org/package/Cabal-1.22.4.0/docs/Distribution-Simple.html#t:UserHooks) for all of the phases of cabal which you can control.

Some examples:

- SDL - uses `autoconfUserHooks` to have cabal run a `configure` script
- this SO answer contains links to packages which override the `confHook`: https://stackoverflow.com/a/32679607/866915
- See this paste for links to more custom Setup.hs files: http://lpaste.net/142696

> Are relative paths supported in Cabal? couldn't find this mentioned in the guide and bash-like ~ doesn't work

If your library is external to your cabal package, I would consider using `pkg-config` on Unix/Linux systems to have cabal locate the library. See the answers to this SO question: [How to specify dependency on external C library in .cabal?](https://stackoverflow.com/q/4959802/866915)

If your library is part of your cabal package, check out this blog post and related github repo which shows how to write a custom Setup.hs file to build and install the library in the right place for cabal:

- [Haskell and external C++ library - the easy way](http://codinginfinity.me/post/2015-04-18/haskell_and_cpp)
- https://github.com/jakubfijalkowski/haskell-and-cpp

Comment: Nice, thank you very much; I'll look into all these things asap.